# multipattern substitution along with whitespace in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, substitution

Input:

```
"good && toast&&guest &fast& slow||wind ||old|| new || very good"
```

Requirement: replace `" && "` with `"and"` (similarly `" || "` with `"or"`) so my output for above should be as below:

```
"good and toast&&guest &fast& slow||wind ||old|| new or very good"
```

What I tried to do:

```
import re

new_ = {
                                '&&':'and',
                                '||':'or'
}

inpStr = "good && toast&&guest &fast& slow||wind ||old|| new || very good"
replDictRe = re.compile( r'(\s%s\s)' % '\s|\s'.join(map(re.escape, new_.keys())))
oidDesStr = replDictRe.sub(lambda mo:new_.get(mo.group(),mo.group()), inpStr)
print(oidDesStr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
replDictRe = re.compile( r'(?<!\S)(?:{})(?!\S)'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, new_.keys()))) )
```

See the [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/bvTEo3) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cSbYKL/1).

The `(?<!\S)(?:\&\&|\|\|)(?!\S)` pattern means

- `(?<!\S)` - matches a location not immediately preceded with a non-whitespace char (aka left-hand whitespace boundary)
- `(?:\&\&|\|\|)` - either a `&&` or `||` character substring
- `(?!\S)` -  a location not immediately followed with a non-whitespace char  (aka right-hand whitespace boundary).

Comment: Any suggestion why below doesn't work ``` replDictRe = re.compile( r'(\s)(?:{})(\s)'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape,new_.keys())))) ```

Comment: @sakeesh Your match values contain spaces but your dictionary keys do not.